# Android Studio - Why does the ActionBar always show, even when fully disabled?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-actionbar

I recently started with Android application development and have come across an issue with the ActionBar. I am aware that this question has been asked a few times, and so I have made the changes necessary from what I can see from the other articles.

Currently, my main activity looks like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5dt3.png)

As you can see, there is a blue bar at the top of the screen directly under the notification bar where an ActionBar is supposed to be. All of my app themes are (I believe) set to NoActionBar. I would like to get rid of this blue bar so that I can use the entire screen to put my contents.

My code is as follows:

**Main_Activity.Java**

```
package ryanpx2016.golftracker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button regularScorePageActivityButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scoreSheetButton);
        regularScorePageActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegularScorePageActivity.class));
           }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:background="@drawable/scoresheet_button"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/scoresheet_button"
        android:id="@+id/scoreSheetButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/course_buttons"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_golf_courses_button"
        android:id="@+id/myGolfCoursesButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scoreSheetButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/scoreSheetButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/course_buttons"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_minigolf_courses_button"
        android:id="@+id/myMinigolfCoursesButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myGolfCoursesButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ryanpx2016.golftracker" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <activity
            android:name=".RegularScorePageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_regular_score_page"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ryanpx2016.golftracker.RegularScorePageActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>



    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>



    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

I believe this may have something to do with a toolbar, but then again, I don't necessarily know what I'm saying :D

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this from your activity_main.xml :

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: Ohh I see; solved the problem. You're a lifesaver! Thank you thank you!! @Stanojkovic